# How to make animation from popoverview to backview?

Tags: ios, animation

[image: I have a customize imagePickerControl]

when I select a image, I want an animation from the picker to the mainView(which is the blur area), anybody have a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Idea:

1. Create a new temp-ImageView with the selected Image.
2. add this to the window at the exact position of the original-ImageView.
3. remove original-ImageView (if you want so)
4. Move/scale the temp-ImageView over the desired position on the screen.
5. Add the final-ImageView to the desired position in the blue area.
6. Remove temp-ImageView.

You will have to do some calculations with - (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)rect fromView:(UIView *)view
Not sure, but the Picker may lay in a different window than your blue area.

```
CGRect destRect; // position in window, height/width need to be flipped, so the size is correct after rotation

// add a ContainerView so rotation-handling is easier, esp. durring moving/scaling
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:destRect];

// set the frame of the imageView, origin 0/0 so rotation is easy to handle, height/width flipp back
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, destRect.size.height, destRect.size.width)];

// flip layer center as well
[tempImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(camView.center.y, camView.center.x)];

// add the rotation 
[tempImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];

[tempImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Comment: Well. I actually did as this. But here is the problem:
1.my app is landscape mode 
2.when I add the temp-ImageView to the windows, the temp-Imageview has a rotation effect, which makes it look correct in portrait mode but not in landscape mode, that's not I expected. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: Is your app always in landscape mode? If so, it is easy to just add a hardcoded 90-degree rotation to the temp-Imageview, else you have to evaluate the device-orientation. I will add some code-snippet which handles the rotation to my post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This definitely works. but you know, this solution is just a little tedious and not so elegant. Have any better idea?